# Datastore query VERY slow against single indexed property

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a simple query over a single indexed property and it fairly often takes more than 20 seconds, sometimes as much as 45 seconds.  The Kind only has 10k entities and the query is returning about 110.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyKind WHERE MyProperty = 'xyz'
```

Normally this only takes a few seconds (which still feels too long), but occasionally it takes a REALLY long time as described above.

The entities that are returned are not in an entity group, they are all their own root entity.  Would this help if I put them into the same entity group?  They are very related to each other, so it would make sense to change the data model this way.

Just wondering if the physical location of the entities is spread out as it is today and putting them into an entity group would keep them together and eliminate a bunch of rpc overhead.

Comment: What does the rest of the workload look like?  Are there lots of writes with MyProperty = 'xyz"?  Are there lots of entity deletes for MyKind?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas Jim.  There are not a lot of entity deletes.  I don't believe there would be a lot of concurrent writes going on for MyProperty = 'xyz' entities, but I could be wrong.  Anything in GCP console that would help show hot spots in the datastore?

Comment: I took a look at the datastore entities that are having the most issue and I do think it's hotspotting.  I have a couple fields that are indexed but not very well scattered value-wise.  I just need to figure out how to rework things to clean up those hotspots.  Thanks for your input Jim, that kinda spurred me down this path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I invite you to check the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices) with Cloud Datastore. Hotspotting in Cloud Datastore can happen for many reasons:

- indexing properities with with monotonically increasing values (such
  as a NOW() timestamp).
- high read or write rates to lexicographically close documents
- A high rate of reads of non-existent entities can lead to hotspotting

For monitoring and to check for hotspotting I suggest you to use [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) in Stackdriver. Here are the available [Datastore metrics.](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-datastore) if you need more help, ping me.